# Blazor - stopPropagation on event for dynamically created DOM with RenderTreeBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor

I have a component class that generates DOM dynamically. I need to be able to `stopPropagation` on events like onclick, onmouseup etc.

```
protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
{
        int i = 0;
        base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
        builder.OpenElement(i++, Tag);
        builder.AddAttribute(i++, "class", Class);
}
```

I tried to add another attribute and event handler like this, but I'm not sure how to access event variable in the handler:

```
builder.AddAttribute(i++, "onclick", EventCallback.Factory.Create<MouseEventArgs>(this, OnClick));

private void OnClick()
{
   //e.StopPropagation() how do I get event here?      
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [WebRenderTreeBuilderExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web.webrendertreebuilderextensions) class provides extension methods for managing event behavior.

In your case, you can stop the propagation by using the [AddEventStopPropagationAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web.webrendertreebuilderextensions.addeventstoppropagationattribute) extension method:

```csharp
protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
{
    int i = 0;
    base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
    builder.OpenElement(i++, Tag);
    builder.AddAttribute(i++, "class", Class);
    builder.AddAttribute(i++, "onclick", EventCallback.Factory.Create<MouseEventArgs>(this, OnClick));
    builder.AddEventStopPropagationAttribute(i++, "onclick", true);
}

private void OnClick()
{
    // Handle your event   
}
```