How to apply onclick:stopPropagation conditionally in Blazor
I have a button in a component and I use @onclick:stopPropagation to stop the click propagating to the parent component.
<div class="btn btn-danger" @onclick:stopPropagation @onclick="OnButtonClick">

However in some cases I don't want to stop propagation. How do I do that conditionally?

Also see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71910750/blazor-stoppropagation-on-event-for-dynamically-created-dom-with-rendertreebui

I didn't realise that @onclick:stopPropagation took a boolean argument. The fix was:
<div class="btn btn-danger" @onclick:stopPropagation="ShouldStopClickPropagation" @onclick="OnButtonClick">

@code {
   private bool ShouldStopClickPropagation => YourConditionalLogicHere;
}

